# mBART tokenizer.batch_decode not properly generating in target language

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

Using [mBART-large-cc25](https://huggingface.co/facebook/mbart-large-cc25) pretrained model, when trying to make translation from korean to english, the tokenizer does not properly decodes in right target language(en)
I tried with the following code snippet

```py
from transformers import MBartForConditionalGeneration, MBartTokenizer
model = MBartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-cc25")
tokenizer = MBartTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-cc25")
tokenizer.src_lang = "ko_KR"
tokenizer.tgt_lang = "en_XX"
article_ko = "안녕하세요. 반갑습니다. 이건 테스트입니다."
translate_en = "hello nice to meet you this is a test"
pt_inputs = tokenizer(article_ko, return_tensors="pt")

preds = model.generate(**pt_inputs, decoder_start_token_id=tokenizer.lang_code_to_id["en_XX"])
converted_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(ids = pt_inputs["input_ids"][0], skip_special_tokens=True)
decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)
converted_tokens_pred = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(ids = preds[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(f"original sentence: {article_ko}")
print(f"traslated sentence:{translate_en}")
print(f"origin_sen_encoded: {pt_inputs}")
print(f"origin_sen_encoded_to_tokens:{converted_tokens}")    
print(f"model prediction:{preds}")
print(f"model prediction decoded:{decoded_preds}")
print(f"model prediction decoded to tokens: {converted_tokens_pred}")
```

And I got the following result.

```
original sentence: 안녕하세요. 반갑습니다. 이건 테스트입니다.
traslated sentence:hello nice to meet you this is a test
origin_sen_encoded: {'input_ids': tensor([[107687,      5,  20451,  54272,  16367,      5, 199323, 153924,   5826,
              5,      2, 250014]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}
origin_sen_encoded_to_tokens:['▁안녕하세요', '.', '▁반', '갑', '습니다', '.', '▁이건', '▁테스트', '입니다', '.']
model prediction:tensor([[250004,      0, 107687,      5,  20451,  54272,  16367,      5, 199323,
         153924,   5826,      5,      2]])
model prediction decoded:['안녕하세요. 반갑습니다. 이건 테스트입니다.']
model prediction decoded to tokens: ['▁안녕하세요', '.', '▁반', '갑', '습니다', '.', '▁이건', '▁테스트', '입니다', '.']
```

how can i make the model predict in right target language?